# ImportError: cssselect does not seem to be installed. See http://packages.python.org/cssselect/

Tags: python, lxml

I have installed using pip install cssselect but I am still not able to import it?? I am on Windows.

Comment: Could you add your code sample, and a stacktrace?

Answer (score 0):

Do you have multiple versions of python installed?

a scenario can be that you installed this package in pip for python 2.7 while you try to import it in python 3 --> that will not work. Try figuring out if you use the same python version for both pip install and the python shell you try to import on.

for python 3 you can use pip3 or something

Answer (score 0):

The problem was that when installing via pip, it was not creating a directory structure inside site-packages.

To solve the problem we have to download cssselect from github, decompress and copy the dir cssselect that's inside cssselect-master to your python site-packages.

It worked!!!